# What is a good rule of thumb for distance between support studs in a banquette seat?

Tags: built-ins

I am going to build built-in seating for my dining room. Planning a 6' span and a 5' span in an "L" shape in one corner of my dining room. I have a decent plan in mind, but I am not sure how to decide how to space the supports. I plan to have the cushions removable and a small (18" to 24") hinged lid on each seat for bonus storage (board games, etc).
Frame will be 20" wide, 14" tall at seat, and (24") between spans. Back will go up from seat area ~3" from back to give it a slight lean using angled cut on 30" high back.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! What material / wood species are you planning to use, and can you share the plan you have in mind?

Comment: @mmathis - Like I said, I have a plan in mind. Nothing so formal. I am using primarily 2x4x8 stock for the frame, 3/4" plywood for the seat, and beadboard for the decorative exposed areas. Here is a similar plan to what I am going to do: [link]https://www.pinterest.com/pin/26810560254735636/

Comment: While it sounds like a wonderful space saving idea, bench seating is horrible for day to day usage.  Everyone has to arrive at the table in the correct order.  People have to move when someone needs to slide in or out etc.  Doing it in a restaurant on a one off basis is one thing, doing it for every meal at home is another.

Comment: What's the other dimension? With 3/4" plywood you won't need crossbars for a span of up to about 24". [Please add new information to the question, not comments.]

Comment: For anyone else interested, using a sag-calculator will answer questions like this for other types/dimensions of wood. http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 3/4" plywood you won't need crossbars for a span of up to about 24" (similar to a typical new home's subfloor arrangement). Beyond that it may start to get bouncy.

In the bizarre case where you'd have a very deep seat, you'd want crossbars at 16-24" intervals.